# How to check for values ending with decimal .00 in a column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a column named Total Amount, and in that there are n number of values, but I have to only find the ones which end with .00

For eg, $102.65, 108.99, 103.00.

Out of these three values I only want those values which end with .00

Comment: `where round(myColumn, 0) = myColumn`

Comment: @allmhuran that definitely won't work if they can start with '$'

Comment: what type is this column?  do `show create table yourtablename;` to see

Comment: WHERE MyColumn LIKE '%.00"; Selects all rows where the field ends with ".00". I think that your values are stored in VARCHARs.

Comment: @ysth yes, I originally wrote that into my comment, but deleted it and put the correct answer instead. if numeric data is being stored as varchar, there are bigger problems to solve.